# Munin throws "SNMPv3 support is unavailable"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, munin

I'm trying to configure a DiskStation to use SNMP. I get following error when performing `munin-node-configure` on my ubuntu system:

```
root@server:/# munin-node-configure --snmp 10.0.0.2 --snmpversion 3 --snmpusername munin --snmpauthpass (something) --shell --debug
...
# Dropping host '10.0.0.2': SNMPv3 support is unavailable (Required module Crypt/DES.pm not found)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right Perl cryptomodules need to be installed.

Do an `apt-get install libcrypt-des-perl` to get the right module.

Additionally, `apt-get install libdigest-hmac-perl` will install the Digest/HMAC module. If this is skipped then following error will be displayed:

```
# Dropping host '10.0.0.2': SNMPv3 support is unavailable (Required module Digest/HMAC.pm not found)
```

Comment: Awesome exactly what I was looking for, thanks for sharing!